# how to redirect back to log in page when the session has been ended in php?

Tags: php

like in when you logged out, it redirects automatically into the log in page.
when I use this code

it just says "**this page isn't working** localhost redirected to many times

Comment: Guessing that you're running this code even on the login page.

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: Without the code , we cannot answer this

Comment: There is a loop hole in your redirection condition. Please share you code!

Answer (score 2):

Set the session and session variable after user login successful  if user click log-out then unset session variable or destroy the session 
**Login-check page :**

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['login']=true;
header("location:dashbord.php");
```

**Log-out page:**

```
session_start();
unset($_SESSION['login']);
if(!isset($_SESSION['login']) && empty($_SESSION['login'])){
       header("location:index.php");
       die;
    }
```